# laravel axios vue.js / Error to connect to database

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

(I edited my code and it's working !)

I’m trying to get my database objects to use them with Vue and Laravel.

my data.blade.php :slight_smile:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Tab test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.5.1/css/bulma.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <users></users>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/customers.js"></script>
</html>
```

my customers.js

```
Vue.component('users',{
    template : `
        <table class="users">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Creation Data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="user in users">
                    <th>{{ user.id }}</th>
                    <th>{{ user.lastname }}</th>
                    <th>{{ user.email }}</th>
                    <th>{{ user.created_at }}</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    `,
    data: function() {
        return {
            users: []
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        this.getUsers();
    },
          methods: {
                    getUsers: function(){


                        axios.get("/apps").then((response) => {this.apps = response.data})
    }
                    }

}),
new Vue({
    el: '#app',


});
```

And my api.php

```
Route::get('/users', function(){
    return App\User::all();
})->name('api_users');
```

And my errors are :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN4iV.png)

Do you have an idea ? I think it's a problem with axios but I don't know how to solve it. ?

Thanks for any ideas or solutions :)

Comment: `axios.get("{{route('api_users') }}")` is your problem. You need to pass the actual url that you want `axios` to make a request to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{route('api_users') }}` is a blade function and cannot be used in your `.js` file.

you could:

- hardcode the url `/users` in your javascript file
- bind the routes to the frontend in blade and access it through there
- etc

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly ! Like that :  axios.get("/customers/list/data")
    .then(response => {this.users = response.data.users})
    } ?

Comment: according to your routes `api_users` is `/users` and not `/customers/list/data`, but that is the general idea yes

Comment: try `axios.get("/users")`

Comment: I tried it but it said nothing, but no errors. It didn't detext Vue.js anymore.

Comment: try `this.users = response.data`

Comment: methods: {
        getUsers: function(){
        this.users = response.data;
        } and it says : [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: `axios.get("/users").then((response) => {this.users = response.data})`

Comment: Yeahhh !! Thank you so much !